# Função para alterar Height com erros

Tags: javascript, resize, funções

```
184 function bannerPrincipal(){
185     var bannerHolder = document.getElementById("banner-principal");
186     var windowSize = window.innerHeight;
187     bannerHolder.css.height == windowSize+"px";
188 }bannerPrincipal();
```

Estou tentando alterar a altura da div "banner-principal" com o código acima, porém, no console aparece o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
>       at bannerPrincipal (index.php:187)
>       at index.php:188

Como posso corrigir o problema ? e o que está o causando ?

Comment: `}bannerPrincipal();` - qual a ideia dessa linha? foi erro a copiar para aqui?

Comment: @Sergio é uma IIFE "tabajara".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bannerHolder.css.height == windowSize + 'px';
```

deveria ser

```
bannerHolder.style.height = windowSize + 'px';
```

Comment: nesse trecho `bannerHolder.css.height == windowSize+'px'` você está comparando em condição ou acrescentando valor?

Comment: É mesmo @LuizAugustoNeto, não tinha reparado. Editei a resposta.